# How to prevent a field from showing up

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I am using [Objectionjs](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js)

In my Model, I have defined a password field.

I want to prevent this field from showing up for all queries - select, inserts, updates etc - that is, after making a query, I don't want this field to be present in the object returned

Is there a method on the model itself that I can use to do this or do I need to omit the field in each query that I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example override `$afterInsert`, `$afterUpdate`, `$afterGet` and make sure that fields are deleted in those hooks.

http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#_s_afterinsert

If you just don't like that some fields are show when you are converting model to json, for example for returning model to client, then overriding `$formatJson` might be enough.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a little bit more, if your are using [`$formatJson`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#_s_formatjson) in your Model:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

// ...

$formatJson(jsonRaw) {
  // Remember to call the super class's implementation.
  const json = super.$formatJson(jsonRaw);
  // Do your conversion here.
  return _.pick(json, ['id', 'email']);
}
```

Will do it.

My 2cs.